# SAS drive space check

Tags: sas

the following code checks all the drives available in the system about their space. How can I make it print only the information about the G: drive which is also a network drive? And print it in gigabytes instead of bytes? Thanks :)

```
%let xmldata = %sysfunc(pathname(work))\wmic_output.xml;
%let xmlautomap  = %sysfunc(pathname(work))\wmic_output-automap.xml;
%let xmlmap =  %sysfunc(pathname(work))\wmic_output-map.xml;

filename wmic "&xmldata" encoding="utf-16";
filename wmicmap "&xmlmap";

filename gather pipe "wmic logicaldisk get name,size,freespace /format:rawxml > ""&xmldata""";

data _null_;
infile gather;
input;
put _infile_;
rc = sleep(.1,1);
run;

libname wmic xmlv2 automap=replace xmlmap=wmicmap;

proc copy in=wmic out=work;
run;

proc transpose data=work.property out=properties(drop=_name_) suffix=_text;
by instance_ordinal;
id property_name;
var value; 
run;

filename gather;
filename wmic;
filename wmicmap;
title1 "Available space in G: drive, if there is less than 1GB available,   please contact the team";
proc print data=work.property noobs;
run;
title; footnote;


title1 "There is less than 1GB available, please contact the BA team";
proc print data=work.property;
var PROPERTY_NAME value;
WHERE instance_ordinal=(4);
/*where property_name='FreeSpace';*/
run;
title; footnote;
```

Comment: Could you edit your post? Put four spaces in the beginning of each line so that it renders properly. Some of your \* operators became text formatting.

Comment: Just did, I hope it works now.

Comment: The whole point of having a preview window is that you can check whether the markdown works before posting. That didn't. The spaces need to be at the *start* of the line, not between the numbers and the code.

Comment: I get it, but is it ok now?

Answer (score 2):

Tazz:

The Pro about `/format:rawxml` is that you do not need to write an input statement.  The Con is that you have to deal with the XML and reshape it.

Suppose you removed the /format:rawxml.  The wmic output could be filtered with a `FIND` -- however you would have to contend with inputting data that is inconsistent.  Consider unformatted output that wmic delivers on my system.

```
> wmic logicaldisk get name,size,freespace
FreeSpace      Name  Size
356353708032   C:    536394588160
348834766848   D:    500104687616
               E:
68748967936    G:    128278560768
1173479329792  H:    3000579911680
```

E: is a Blue-ray drive with no disk.  I can't think of a simple one line input statement that could handle the E: row without error. That is why I used rawxml in my answer to your other question.  The automap did all the standardized inputting, and the transpose reshaped the data.

However, if you filter to a drive that you know will have data in all columns you can use remove /format and add FIND to the pipe.  Then a single DATA Step can read the result, scale the bytes and generate a status message:

```
filename gspot pipe "wmic logicaldisk get name,size,freespace | find ""G:""";

%let status = G: *NOT FOUND*;
data _null_;
  infile gspot;
  attrib freespace length=8 name length=$2;
  input freespace name;
  freespaceGB = round(freespace / 1000**3,0.1);
  * robust if, in case pipe delivered more than expected;
  if name = "G:" then call symput ('status', "G: has " || cat(freespaceGB) || "GB free");
run;

%put NOTE: &=status;
```

If you stick with the XML input method you can DATA Step over the the transposed data to generate your status message.  In this example there is no Proc COPY from wmic library to work -- transpose reads data directly from the wmic library:

```
* ... libname prep ... *;

libname wmic xmlv2 automap=replace xmlmap=wmicmap;

proc transpose data=wmic.property out=work.properties(drop=_name_) suffix=_text;
by instance_ordinal;
id property_name;
var value; 
run;
```

You could filter directly in the transpose output dataset options, for example `out=work.properties(drop=_name_ where=(name_text="G:"))`

Generate your status message

```
%let status = G: *NOT FOUND*;
data _null_;
  set work.properties;
  freespace = input (freespace_text, best12.);
  freespaceGB = round(freespace / 1000**3,0.1);
  if name_text = "G:" then call symput ('status', "G: has " || cat(freespaceGB) || "GB free");
run;

%put NOTE: &=status;
```

Comment: Actually, print in HTML only if there is 1GB or less left in the G drive! :)

Answer (score 2):

`wmic` seems like overkill here - if all you want is free space, how about plain old `dir`?

```
filename cmd pipe "dir G:\ | findstr /c:""bytes free""";

data _null_;
  infile cmd;
  input;
  free_space_gb = input(scan(_infile_,3,' '), comma20.) * 2**-30;
  put "There is currently " free_space_gb 8.2 "GB of free space on the G drive";
  call symput('free_space_gb',free_space_gb); /*Create macro variable*/
run;

%macro print_alert_html;
  %if &free_space_gb < 1 %then %do;
    ods listing close;
    ods html file = "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\report.html";
      ods html text = "Alert: only &free_space_gb GB of space left on the G drive!";
    ods html close;
    ods listing;
  %end;
%mend;
```

You then need to run the macro, and if it triggers you should be able to open the html report it generates:

```
%print_alert_html;
x explorer "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\report.html";
```

Comment: Actually, print in HTML only if there is 1GB or less left in the G drive! :)

Comment: This is really a separate question, but I've included a basic example above.

Comment: The marco print_alert_html doesn't work, could you please reformulate it with a proc print data=? thanks

Comment: 1. Did you run the macro? 2. Was the condition true? 3. Did you try opening the html it generated? In what sense did it 'not work'?

Comment: Well, sorry, it works but it's just that the output should be print with a proc print instead of macro! thanks :)

Comment: There is no dataset to print - only a single line of text. Is there some other aspect of the proc print output that you require? In any case, a macro is required for conditional execution.

Comment: And this is because I have to integrate the code in an already existing program. Else your solution so far is working great! For example, I would like to it work with a proc print data=..... and then run; :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the simple output puts the columns in a different order than you asked for them. But if it does it consistently then it should not be hard to work with. To deal with the missing FREESPACE value you can try pre-reading the first two characters.

```
data disks ;
  infile 'wmic logicaldisk get name,size,freespace' pipe firstobs=2 truncover ;
  length name $2 size freespace 8 ;
  input name $2. @1 @ ;
  if name = ' ' then input name ;
  else input freespace name size ;
  if name ne ' ';
  format size freespace comma32. ;
run;
```

So testing on your example output.

```
data disks ;
  infile cards firstobs=2 truncover ;
  length name $2 size freespace 8 ;
  input name $2. @1 @ ;
  if name = ' ' then input name ;
  else input freespace name size ;
  if name ne ' ';
  format size freespace comma32. ;
cards;
FreeSpace      Name  Size
356353708032   C:    536394588160
348834766848   D:    500104687616
               E:
68748967936    G:    128278560768
1173479329792  H:    3000579911680

;
```

Yields this result.

[image]